# Swift 3 - SQLite wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, swift3

I'm new to swift and mobile and I'm starting an app in which I will use SQLite and I was looking for a wrapper, I really liked [this one](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) but it seems not to be compatible with swift 3.

I'm looking for swift 3 compatible wrappers, any suggestions?

Comment: I have no experience with https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift that you linked to, but did you notice that there is a Swift 3 branch?

Comment: I did. But since I'm starting with mobile and swift I think it would not be a good idea to work with a branch that is not the final release, if some error happen because of it I will be lost.

Comment: @AndréLuiz, it´s working good with that branch no issues. I´m using it myself it´s reliable.

Comment: @RashwanL OK. I will try then, thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `SQLite` with `Swift 3.0` add the the following to your `podfile`:

```
pod 'SQLite.swift', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git',
       :branch => 'swift3-mariotaku'
```

Comment: Thanks, i had seen this branch but I was a bit afraid to use it but @RashwanL told that it is in a good state, so I will be using it.